# Spyder (Python 35) Audio

Tags: python-3.x, audio, spyder

I use python 3.5 on windows 64 bits, and I have been trying to get some sounds into my code.

I tried two programs in spyder but I still can't get it to work. Both of the programs run without errors, but I cannot hear any sounds. I think the problem might be with spyder itself? I am not sure. I tried resetting spyder setting but still it did not work. Can anyone please help?

Both of the codes:

```
import pygame
#import os
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
sounda= pygame.mixer.Sound("b001c012.wav")
#os.system

sounda.play()





import os
from datetime import datetime

debug = True

def playASound(x):
    if debug == True:
        print(x,end = ' - ')
        print(daysound[x])

    todaysound = 'aplay' + sayDayDirectory + daysound[x] + '.wav -R 1'
    os.system(todaysound)

sayDayDirectory = '/home/pi/exercise\ files/dayOfWeekSounds/'
daysound = ['monday','tuesday','wednesday','thursday','friday','saturday','sunday']
todaysDate = datetime.now()
todaysDay = datetime.weekday(todaysDate)

playASound(todaysDay)

if debug == True:
    print('other sounds are ')
    for n in range(0,7):
        playASound(n)
```